# Geo Point vs Location

Tags: android, location, distance, geo

This is maybe a noob question but im not 100% sure about it.

How can i make a Location Object using Geo points? I want to use it to get the distance between two points.
I already found a thread where it says

```
Location loc1 = new Location("Location"); 
loc.setLatitude(geoPoint.getLatitudeE6);
loc.setLongitude(geoPoint.getLongitudeE6);

Location loc2 = new Location("Location2");
loc2.setLatitude(geoPoint.getLatitudeE6);
loc2.setLongitude(geoPoint.getLongitudeE6);
```

and then i would use the distanceTo() to get the distance between the two points.

My Questions
What is the Providername for? ...new Location("What is this here???")
So do i have to define a Provider before or something? 
I want to use this code in a for() to calaculate between more GeoPoints. 
And btw - i have to convert the E6 Values back to normal?

Comment: provider is GPS or Network... GPS is accurate but might take some time and Network is opposite to it... Yes you have to set a provider to get a gps fix.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly

loc.setLatitude() takes a double latitude. So the correct code is:

```
  loc.setLatitude( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);
```

Location() constructor take the name of the GPS provider used. It can be  LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER among other values

Comment: ok so i need to define a location manager before - or can i add this "LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER" directly into the brackets like `Location loc = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` ?

Comment: Yeah you dont need LocationManager. and yes that's how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the distance between two point you can use the [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class and more precisely the [distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) static method.

The doc is quite clear on what it does but here a quick code sample:

```
float[] results = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(destLatitude, destLongitude, mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), results);
// result in meters, convert it in km
String distance = String.valueOf(Math.round(results[0] / 1000)) + " km");
```

To convert from minute/second to degree you can use the [convert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#convert%28double,%20int%29) method of the Location class.

Comment: If the answer suits you, please mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
Log.i("MapView", "Map distance to mark (in meters): " + myLocation.distanceTo(GeoToLocation(point)) + "m");
```

then

```
public Location GeoToLocation(GeoPoint gp) {
        Location location = new Location("dummyProvider");
        location.setLatitude(gp.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
        location.setLongitude(gp.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
        return location;
    }
```